# Roslyn INamedTypeSymbol.ContainingNamespace.Name an empty string

Tags: c#, roslyn, sourcegenerators

I have an attribute I'm generating that contains a couple of constructor arguments, a `string` and a `Type`, and I'd really like to get the namespace of the `Type`, because I need to include that in the generated source when using the actual `Type`.

The attribute is like:

```
public MyCustomAttribute : Attribute
{
    public MyCustomAttribute(string info, Type type)
    {
        //...
    }
}
```

My Roslyn code where I'm struggling is:

```
private void Foo(SemanticModel model, SyntaxNode node)
{
    if(model.GtDeclaredSymbol(node) is not INamedTypeSymbol symbol)
    {
        return null;
    }

    var attributeData = symbol.GetAttributes().First(x => AttributeClass.Name == "MyCustomAttribute");
   
    var stringdata = (string)attributeData.ConstructorArguments[0].Value; //this works fine
    var typedata = (INamedTypeSymbol)attributeData.ConstructorArguments[1].Value;

    var typeName = typedata.MetadataName; // works to get the actual type name
    var typeNamespace = typedata.ContainingNamespace.Name; // This is an empty string?

    //...
}
```

Comment: If you look with the debugger at the underlying concrete type of the INamedTypeSymbol, does it have a name like "ErrorTypeSymbol"?

Comment: @JasonMalinowski yes it does.

Comment: Then that means the code you're analyzing isn't valid in some way, so the compiler can't even find type in your typeof. So that means you're missing a reference, using statement, etc.

Comment: And to explain: if the compiler can't find a symbol in some cases it'll create a "fake" symbol to substitute so other APIs and refactoring can still try to function. So for example a refactoring that is moving code around could still carry around a reference to a "broken" symbols as if you pretend it's there.